# C++ - Is my script at home in SRC?

Tags: c++

I'm writing my first cpp program. It will grow and I'm trying to get my head around the folder structure. Based on this site:

http://hiltmon.com/blog/2013/07/03/a-simple-c-plus-plus-project-structure/

Should my main helloworld.cpp go in lib or src? I understand it's overkill folder structure for a helloworld but I'm just trying to understand for the future.

Comment: Your code, your rules if you don't intend anyone else to use it, also some IDE's use filters to impose a structure on your src files even if the folders don't physically exist such as Visual Studio

Comment: You can configure your Apache from httpd.conf  to add bin directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should go in src, as you are writing `c++` code. In general lib folder has your own compiled header files or 3rd party headers/utils.

Answer (score 3):

Since it is a sourcefile you should put it into src.

Answer (score 3):

It will go in your `src` folder as for as lib is concerned it will contain any third party libraries if you are using.

You can also follow the comment of @EdChum,But any how standard  way is to put in `src` folder.